# How to safely pass objects created by new into constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-management, class-design

I have a few classes which look like that:

```
struct equation {};

struct number: equation {
    number(int n): value(n) {}

  private:
    int value;
};

struct operation: equation {
    operation(const equation* left, const equation* right)
        : left(left), right(right) {}

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<equation> left, right;
};
```

They are designed in a way that `operation` takes ownership on the pointers that are passed into constructor.

My question is how can I modify this class to be able to safely use it in a next manner:

```
operation op(new number(123), new number(456));
```

It seems to me that if the first object is created and the second one is not (say exception is thrown from `number` constructor) then it's a memory leak - nobody will ever delete a pointer to the first number.

What can I do with this situation? I do not want to allocate objects sequentially and delete them if something has failed - it's too verbose.

Comment: @StoryTeller My bad, fixed

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr`. This is the situation it's made for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I do not want to allocate objects sequentially and delete them if something has failed - it's too verbose.

Yes. You just need to apply smart pointer idiom more thoroughly; more precisely, change the parameter type to [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), and use [`std::make_unique`  (since C++14)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (instead of using `new` explicitly) to avoid this problem. e.g.

```
struct operation: equation {
    operation(std::unique_ptr<equation> left, std::unique_ptr<equation> right)
        : left(std::move(left)), right(std::move(right)) {}

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<equation> left, right;
};
```

then

```
operation op(std::make_unique<number>(123), std::make_unique<number>(456));
```

Note that the using of `std::make_unique` is important here, the raw pointer created inside `std::make_unique` is guaranteed to be managed by the returned `std::unique_ptr`; even the 2nd `std::make_unique` fails the 
`std::unique_ptr` created by the 1st `std::make_unique` will see to it that the pointer it owns is destroyed. And this is also true for the case that the 2nd `std::make_unique` is invoked first.

Before C++14 you can make your own version of `std::make_unique`; a basic one is easy to write. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique#Possible_Implementation)'s a possible implementation.

```
// note: this implementation does not disable this overload for array types
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: ... Because now each allocation and construction is happening "atomically" inside make_unique.

Comment: It is a c++14 solution, and I think it's fine, but is there a way to do this in c++11?

Comment: I would like to add the reason of using `make_unique`: Caller also has the responsibility in preserving exception safety.

Comment: @RomanGolyshev It's easy to make your own version. See the reference linked in the answer.